# ¿Cómo saber el ancho de una collectionView en iOS, Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

tengo una collectionView que ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla, como quiero tener 10 columnas, tengo este código:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let sizePantalla = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let ancho = sizePantalla.width / CGFloat(10.0)
    return CGSize(width: ancho, height: ancho)
```

Todo va bien, pero quisiera que la collectionView no ocupara todo el ancho de la pantalla, que fuera más pequeño. Este ancho no es fijo en diseño, sino que cambiará según el dispositivo en el que se ejecute la App.
Esta es mi duda: ¿cómo consigo el ancho de la collectionView?

Answer (score 1):

la respuesta es:

```
let availableWidth = collectionView.bounds.inset(by: collectionView.layoutMargins).width
```

Impaciente...

Answer (score 0):

En el Delegate del collection view tienes un parámetro **collectionView** en  **func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView...** eso te indica que el delegate te esta enviando el parámetro del collectionview actual. Lo único que tienes que hacer es cambiar sizePantalla.width por collectionview.frame.width en tu código, así el ancho siempre dependerá del collectionview y no de sizePantalla, el código quedaría algo así:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // calculando ancho 
    let ancho = collectionView.frame.width / CGFloat(10.0)
    // calculando alto (suponiendo que también quieres 10 renglones por pantalla)
    let alto = collectionView.frame. height / CGFloat(10.0)
    return CGSize(width: ancho, height: alto)

}
```